# StMoMo: Start fitting with gnm. Error in eval(family$initialize) : y values must be 0 <= y <= 1

Tags: r

```
library("StMoMo")
library("demography")
library("MLmetrics")
library("grpreg")
library("gtsummary")
library("tidyverse")
library("forecast")
library("tseries")
library("gnm")
library("fds")
library("lifecontingencies")


maldata <- read.demogdata("mort3.txt","mort3.txt",type="mortality",label="mal",skip=0,popskip=0)
maldata

#Extract data 2006 until 2018
maldata1 <- extract.years(extract.ages(maldata, 15:80), 2006:2018)
maldata1s <- smooth.demogdata(maldata1)
head(maldata1)
head(maldata1s)

#plot data
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
plot(maldata1s, series="mortalityrate", main="Malaysian Death Rate",ylab="qx",xlab="age")

#turn into StMoMo data
stmomo <- StMoMoData(maldata1s, series = "mortalityrate")
summary(stmomo)

#Define CBD model
CBD <- cbd(link = c("logit", "log"))


#Model Fitting
ages.fit <- 15:80
years.fit <- 2006:2018
years.fit
cbdfit <- fit(CBD, data = stmomo, ages.fit = ages.fit, years.fit = years.fit)
```

hye, I keep getting the same error which is

```
StMoMo: Start fitting with gnm

Error in eval(family$initialize) : y values must be 0 <= y <= 1
In addition: Warning message:
In fit.StMoMo(CBD, data = stmomo, ages.fit = ages.fit, years.fit = years.fit) :
  logit-Binomial model fitted to central exposure data
```

Can you figure out where did I go wrong?